# create new PDF using TCPDF and import existing PDF into it

Tags: tcpdf

How can I import an existing `pdf` file into the new-created `pdf` using `TCPDF?`

So assume I am currently doing an invoice section. Once the user click print invoice, I will start gather the data and then create a `PDF` using `TCPDF`. However, I need to "attach" another existing PDF into it if available. So assume, in 1 invoice file that is generated from `TCPDF` consists of 5 pages. And then I have to "attach" another existing `PDF` into this file. So total will be 6 pages or more, depends on the existing `PDF` file.  The existing PDF file is uploaded by the user. So, the existing `PDF` file will be uploaded first, then will be added into the new generated invoice file.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: import is working fine for me but it is removing the existing images from the imported pdf . Is there any fix ?

Comment: @MohammadIntsar start a new question for this please.

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve this with the addition of [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/):

```php
<?php
require_once('tcpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

//Merging of the existing PDF pages to the final PDF
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('existing_pdf.pdf');
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i, '/MediaBox');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
}

//Your code relative to the invoice here

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: It remove the existing images from the imported pdf . Is there any fix ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used TCPDI (an extension for TCPDF). You can find it on github https://github.com/pauln/tcpdi. There are also forks ready for composer.

It's easy to use... TCPDI extends TCPDF so constuctor parameters are the same

```
$pdf = new TCPDI(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Then add the pages from your existing pdf file after your pages

```
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($existingPdfPath);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was solving similar problem and I ended up with merging the PDFs using GhostScript from PHP:

```
exec('gs -o ' . $merged_path
    . ' -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDPFSETTINGS=/prepress '
    . $first_pdf_path . ' '
    . $attachment_path);
```

It is working for several years just fine.

Comment: I have no idea what is it sir

Comment: GhostScript is a tool to work with PDFs. I don't know about a way to do that in TCPDF only and the way using GhostScript is very simple. The above line merges two PDFs (`first_pdf`, `attachment`) into `merged`.

Comment: Explaining what you don't understand would be useful if you are interested in solving this issue.